# Capturing a "new window open" event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an IE plugin that contains links. They open in a new window. I want to modify the behaviour so that the links open in a div. I can't make changes to the way the plugin operates so I was thinking to so something like capture the url in the new window and then close the window. Is there a way to monitor for something like a "new window open" event preferably with JavaScript?

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: _"I want to modify the behaviour so that the links open in a div."_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: ok so this part is not the tricky bit. I will probably make it open in an iFrame or something.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="300" height="300" id="leIframe">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>

    <a href="javascript:closeFrame();">[X]</a>


</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeFrame() {
        document.getElementById("leIframe").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

</html>
```